# Where is the Cassalanter contract?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, waterdeep-dragon-heist

In [Waterdeep: Dragon Heist](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/dragonheist), is there a physical copy of the Cassalanter's contract with

> Asmodeus

? If so, where is it? I know that [Victoro's](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Victoro_Cassalanter) desk drawer contains contracts, but I believe those just record who he's lent money to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 115 of the module has one clause of the contract:

> A clause in the contract allows them to preserve their remaining (and
>   future) children's lives by instead paying 'one shy of a million gold
>   coins, and the sacrifice of one shy of one hundred unfortunate souls.

Similar mentions are made on a couple other pages of the module, but there is no mention of any written/ physical contract anywhere in the adventure. It's possible that the contract is purely verbal. Another possibility is that Asmodeus has it, or else it is somewhere else outside of Waterdeep.